# Creating new fabric canvas changes canvas position

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to learn about fabricjs and noticed that when i create a new fabric.Canvas object it changes the position of my canvas.

HTML

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Css

```
#c {
border: thin red solid;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'cheese.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  
};

// applying the below line shifts the canvas element back to 0,0 position
var cFabric = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

Hoping you guys know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Calling the fabric.Canvas constructor on your native canvas element will result in your native canvas getting wrapped by a `.canvas-container` div. The original canvas gets an added `.lower-canvas` class and its `left, right` css styles are set to `0px`. Other then that, a sibling canvas is added below your original canvas, with a class of `upper-canvas`. These two canvases act like layers, managed by the inner workings of Fabric.js (magic :O).

If you need to position and style your canvas, I recommend you wrap your html canvas with a wrapper div.

```
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

Next transfer your css rules to the wrapper

```
#canvas-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Here's a simple fiddle that I made by updating @Mullainathan's sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eo7vdg1t/1/